# The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship. Net Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I'm upgrading a netcore project from version 2.2 to 3.1. I've managed to make it build but on runtime I'm getting this error:

> {"The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory.QuizLimits' and 'CustomCategoryQuizLimits.RestaurantCustomCategory'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details."}

This is the code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory>()
                .HasKey(t => new {t.RestaurantId, t.QuestionCategoryId});
}
```

RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory:

```
public class RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory : IQuizTimeLimitable
    {

        public RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory()
        {
            QuizLimits = new CustomCategoryQuizLimits(this);
        }
        public int QuestionCategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("QuestionCategoryId")]
        public CustomCategory QuestionCategory { get; set; }

        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RestaurantId")]
        public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }

        public CustomCategoryQuizLimits QuizLimits { get; set; }

        public void UpdateQuizTimeLimit(CustomCategoryQuizLimits item)
        {
            this.QuizLimits = item;
        }

        public QuizLimitsBase GetQuizLimits()
        {
            return QuizLimits;
        }
    }
```

CustomCategoryQuizLimits:

```
 public class CustomCategoryQuizLimits : QuizLimitsBase
    {
        public CustomCategoryQuizLimits(RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory restaurantCustomCategory)
        {
            RestaurantCustomCategory = restaurantCustomCategory;
        }

        public CustomCategoryQuizLimits()
        {
        }

        public CustomCategoryQuizLimits(
            RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory restaurantCustomCategory
            , QuizQuestionsLimit limitsQuizQuestionsLimit
            , QuizTimeLimit    limitsQuizTimeLimit
        ) : base(limitsQuizQuestionsLimit, limitsQuizTimeLimit)
        {
            RestaurantCustomCategory = restaurantCustomCategory;
        }

        [Column("CustomCategoryId")]
        public int QuestionCategoryId { get; set; }

        [Column("CustomCategory_RestaurantId")]
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

        public RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory RestaurantCustomCategory { get; private set; }

        public override QuizLimitsBase GetDefault()
        {
            return new CustomCategoryQuizLimits();
        }

        public override int GetChainId()
        {
            return RestaurantCustomCategory.Restaurant.ChainId;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<int> GetRestaurantIds()
        {
            return new List<int>() {RestaurantCustomCategory.RestaurantId};
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what I have to change to fix this so I would love a bit of help.

Comment: Are you sure `[Column("CustomCategoryId")]` and `[Column("CustomCategory_RestaurantId")]` are correct?

Comment: @Dai Yes. Project on its 2.2 original version works fine as far as I know and it has this same code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It seems on the transitions to 3.0 EF gets confused with one to one relationships. So I added this on the Fluent:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory>()
                .HasKey(t => new {t.RestaurantId, t.QuestionCategoryId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<RestaurantCustomQuestionCategory>()
                .HasOne(t => t.QuizLimits)
                .WithOne(i => i.RestaurantCustomCategory)
                .HasForeignKey<CustomCategoryQuizLimits>(t => new { t.RestaurantId, t.QuestionCategoryId });
}
```